# Magento 2 admin css and js not loading after trying to change admin URL

Tags: javascript, css

To change my admin_url of Magento I did it first with: `Store > Advanced Tab > Admin Base URL section`

After that the admin CSS and js weren't working and to solve that I tried it with the command in SSH:

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="admin_path"
```

now still no js and CSS is loading in the admin.  I tried the commands below to solve but there's still no CSS and JS in admin, in frontend everything is working:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f  nl_NL
```

> - Removing static files except .htaccess
> - Reindexing

Changing the following content:
`Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink`
To:
`Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: What errors are you getting in browser console

Comment: Please try to use this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040496/magento-2-not-loading-css-and-javascript

Comment: Hi Raj, i added a screenshot

Comment: Is frontend working fine?

Comment: Yes frontend is working fine 100%

Comment: In which mode, is your Magento running, i.e. **developer** or **production**?

Comment: It's on developer mode.

Comment: Hi.


In the source file of the page i see that it's trying to call the css and js files from

https://www.DOMAIN.nl/admin_secret/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/nl_NL/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css  . When opening this link it redirects to the admin backend without opening the css.

if i try to open this link without admin_secret in the url it opens the css file correct

Comment: @user1250934, please check whether your locale for the backend is the same, for which you are deploying the static content?

Comment: Hi Mohit, how can i check that?

Comment: To check the locale of the backend, please open **admin_user** table in the database and find the value of **interface_locale**.

Comment: it's nl_NL, like the frontend.

Comment: hmm, I think you have set the value of **Use Custom Admin URL** also, instead of chaning the value of **Use Custom Admin Path** only. Please confirm.

Comment: @user1250934, please follow my answer. The problem will be rectified.

Comment: @user1250934, please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem appears when we set the backend setting for **Use Custom Admin URL** wrong.

To get rid of this problem, follow the steps mentioned below:

- Login to the database and open the **`core_config_data`** table.
- Find and remove the row having the path like **admin/url/custom**.
- Now find the value where

> scope = **stores**
>
> scope_id = **0**
>
> path = **web/secure/base_url** and **web/unsecure/base_url** respectively.

and delete these rows.

- Now, set the value to **0** where you find the path like **admin/url/use_custom**.

Flush Magento cache and check the backend again. It should be working with the old backend URL again.

**Update:** After getting back to the old backend URL, if you wish to change the backend URL, just follow the steps below:

> 1. Open app/etc/env.php and find the section:

```
'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin'
    ],
```

> 2. Change the value **admin** to any other value of your choice.